# Difference between NOT LIKE and '[^string]'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any difference between the 2 syntaxes?

```
SELECT [dbo].[Employees].[FirstName]
FROM [dbo].[Employees]
WHERE [dbo].[Employees].[FirstName] NOT LIKE '[a-c]%';

SELECT [dbo].[Employees].[FirstName]
FROM [dbo].[Employees]
WHERE [dbo].[Employees].[FirstName] LIKE '[^a-c]%';
```

Comment: I've tagged as SQL Server. Since your SQL is not standard, I assumed you wanted an answer for that DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One will match an empty string. The other will not.

And for more complex patterns, there's almost always a difference. Especially if you start exploiting double-negatives e.g. if you have a `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` pattern, there's no simple way to reduce it.